# Impala Data Locality

Tags: cloudera, impala, bigdata

I have a question about data locality in impala,
lets say I have cluster with 10 data nodes(on each data node there is impalad),
if I executing query in impala `SELECT * FROM big_table where dt='2017' where blabla orderby blabla group by blabla` (lets say its a big query).

and lets say the files under partition (dt=2017') is in dn 1,3,5
so if I'll execute the query will the coordinator use only daemons 1,3,5 for data locality or it'll use all the daemons, and the other daemons will read this data remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question: it uses only daemons 1,3,5 for data locality.

This is generally a scheduling problem. Impala make such decisions in `simple-scheduler.cc`.

```
// We schedule greedily in this order:
// cached collocated replicas > collocated replicas > remote (cached or not) replicas.
```

Impala will not use other backends to scan a datanode if there is one backend colocated. And for fragments without a scannode, like partitioned aggregation node, impala puts them on the same location as their input fragments reside.

```
  // there is no leftmost scan; we assign the same hosts as those of our
  // leftmost input fragment (so that a partitioned aggregation fragment
  // runs on the hosts that provide the input data)
```